# Using the von Neumann crossed product to introduce a measure on the orbit space?

Tags: reference-request, ergodic-theory, topological-groups, von-neumann-algebras, haar-measure

Suppose we're given an action (possibly: ergodic) of a group G (say, $\mathbb{R}$) on a measure space $(X, \mu)$ (possibly: a standard probability space).

**Question:** is there a natural way of using the crossed product $L^{\infty} X \rtimes G$ to introduce a measure on the orbit space $X/G$ (or some representation thereof)? And if there is, what are the properties of the measure (especially: in relation to the push forward measure)?

I'd be grateful for some standard references on the topic!

**Background:** it's been hinted in the comments section here, I think: [How to define the quotient of a measure which is invariant under group action?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40329/how-to-define-the-quotient-of-a-measure-which-is-invariant-under-group-action) that this is indeed possible but no details were provided.

Comment: In general the full collection of orbits would not form a measurable partition (think of the flow of an irrational flow on the unit torus). One might consider finite-time trajectories (as in the case of defining conditional measures), or try to construct leafwise measures a-la Lindenstruass (but this has only been done in the homogeneous case so far). What do you mean by using the semi-direct product here? How do you pushforward a measure here, especially when the target space is non-measurable (say non Borel measurable).

Comment: @Asaf thank you for your reply! I'll look up leafwise measures.


Suppose we've got an action Lie groupoid, $\mathcal{G} \rightrightarrows M$. I've seen suggestions that in this particular case, the orbit space, $X/G$, can be thought of as represented by the stack $X//\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: For instance, one idea would be to identify something that can play the role of $C_c(X//\mathcal{G})$ and say that a linear functional (subject to some conditions) on $C_c(X//\mathcal{G})$ gives us a measure on $X//\mathcal{G}$. This is the approach taken in M. Crainic and J. N. Mestre in "[Measures on Differentiable Stacks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.01673.pdf)". What they do is they take $C_c(X//\mathcal{G})$ to be just the convolution algebra of the groupoid. Whether this allows one to recover any set measures on $X/G$, I'm not sure. (That's the closest I've seen to using $X \rtimes G$).

Comment: Then there's A. Weinstein's approach from "[The Volume of a Differentiable Stack](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.2130.pdf)", which also involves looking at $X//\mathcal{G}$. There, I think, some subsets of $X/G$ do get assigned a measure (see Definition 3.3).

(And what I had in mind re: pushforward measure was: whenever $X/G$ corresponds to a partition of $X$ into measurable sets, what are the relations between the pushforward measure [i.e. $\hat{\mu}(A) = \mu_X(\pi^{-1}(A))$, $A \subset X/G$, with $\pi: X \rightarrow X/G$ being the natural projection] and some other natural measures on $X/G$?)

Comment: the partition (to full orbits) would very rarely consist of measurable sets, as already indicated in the cases of unipotent flows. So I don't see any reason/meaning in discussing this hypothetical scenario. If one uses a measurable partition to beginwith, there's an ample literature about conditional measures. I don't understand the stacky approach, IT IS CLEAR that it is enough to consider transversal measures, as the measure on each orbit itself (not closure) is Haar in the orbit direction... I don't understand how this discussion of theirs is relevant/general or can implemented...